# gcloud sql instances create --options

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to create new cloud-sql instance using gcloud sdk terminal using `gcloud sql instances create` command.

There are multiple optional parameters we can pass along with the command.
For example --activation-policy ACTIVATION_POLICY, 
In the documentation it is not mentioned, what are the valid options(values) we can pass in for this parameter?

Please share if this is available anywhere in the documentation.
If it is there somewhere, it is not so obvious or not accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that, you can see the valid values here:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/insert

> Valid values:
>
> ALWAYS: The instance is on; it is not deactivated by
>   inactivity.
>
> NEVER: The instance is off; it is not activated, even if
>   a connection request arrives.
>
> ON_DEMAND: The instance responds to
>   incoming requests, and turns itself off when not in use. Instances
>   with PER_USE pricing turn off after 15 minutes of inactivity.
>   Instances with PER_PACKAGE pricing turn off after 12 hours of
>   inactivity.

We should include this information in the create command help.